# How to save base64 data as png image to server?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can i save a base64data string as png image to server?

Below code is for php but i am using nodejs as backend.
I am sending base64data through ajax call.

```
list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
$data = base64_decode($data);
file_put_contents('myDirectory/filename.png', $data);
```

Comment: Decode the base64 data. Write the data to a file - Now you know the steps, search for how to accomplish each individually, and then combine them. There is no problem here, only a request for code translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [filesystem API](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html).

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile("/tmp/test.png", $data, "binary", function(err) {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log("The file was saved!");
  }
});
```

Also see [here](http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/file-system/how-to-write-files-in-nodejs)