# Store as Png Image from Signature pad?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, signaturepad

I have implement [Signature-Pad](https://devdactic.com/signature-drawpad-ionic/) and its working.
so, now I want to store the Signature as `.png` image to `local/cloudinary`.

```
$scope.saveCanvas = function() {
  var sigImg = signaturePad.toDataURL('image/png');
  $scope.signature = sigImg;
  console.log("$scope.signature :",$scope.signature);
}
```

above code gives `base64` string like : `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAASwAAACWCAYAAABkW7XSAAAY`

How can I convert the `base64` into `.png` image?

I have tried :[angular-base64](https://github.com/ninjatronic/angular-base64)

```
 $scope.decoded = $base64.decode(sigImg);
```

I don't know how to use [this..](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23534071/4302328)

thanx..!

Comment: Have you found a solution to this question? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using the following code:

```
const dataURL = this.signaturePad.toDataURL('image/png');
const data = atob(dataURL.substring('data:image/png;base64,'.length)),
  asArray = new Uint8Array(data.length);

for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; ++i) {
  asArray[i] = data.charCodeAt(i);
}

const blob = new Blob([asArray], { type: 'image/png' });
```

Then you should be able to upload the `blob` to cloudinary.

I took this code from the following [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17332071/trying-to-save-canvas-png-data-url-to-disk-with-html5-filesystem-but-when-i-ret/17332272#17332272)